# Fully restoring Portable Chrome Profiles after OS/Windows Reinstall

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I had to reinstall Windows 7 and eventually test something in Chrome; I only use portable versions. The profiles *half* work however some of the very limited customizations aren't working (e.g. the Home button isn't displayed though the theme is working).

I ran `chrome://version/` and it says my profile location is: C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\Chrome\72.0\Data\profile\Default

I suspect that something in the `C:\Users\[user]\AppData` directory needs to be restored or fixed (doubting it's a registry issue). How do I *fully* restore Portable Chrome profiles?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design of the Chrome/Chromium team.

Your passwords, search providers, homepage settings, extensions, extension settings,
etc. are all locked to a specific PC and you cannot move them around.
You cannot back them up and restore then to another PC.
You must log in to Google for all of that.

Signing into Google Chrome should restore your settings if you were signed in last time, but it will be required that you do so and re-download your settings and extensions on every PC. If you're not signed in to Google, you'll simply lose your settings. Google Chrome is designed to not give you any notice of this except a small message at the top of the Options window if you happen to open it.

If you want to use those things portably without having to sync it all to Google, you have to use a different browser.
The Chrome/Chromium team is working on improving this problem, but it's unknown
when and if improvements will arrive.

More details are available on the Google Chrome Portable homepage and in the license page presented during installation:

Comment: This does not match my experience.  I have used the same Profile for Portable Chromium/Chrome for several PC now.

Comment: @Ramhound: With sync or without?

Comment: I don't sync my profile with Google.

Comment: @Ramhound: If you are somehow bypassing this "feature" of Chrome, it would be useful to tell us how.

Comment: I simply copy a folder that contains `Portable Chromium` and my profile.  `Portable Chromium` isn't current, but I have verified the current version of `Portable Chrome` still allows me to move a folder that contains my profile (and the application) around to multiple machines.

Comment: @Ramhound: You could perhaps compare notes with the poster to find what you are doing that he doesn't.

Comment: @harrymc I run Chrome portable so I can test older versions; my reasons are objectively valid. I won't down-vote this post, most designers/developers/etc aren't aware that you can run Chrome as a portable program. I save the original `AppData` directories from older copies of Windows so if I need to go back and easily restore a configuration I can; a heck of a lot easier than manually setting everything up when you already have...unless you're dealing with Google. -_-

Comment: @John: Are you running Chrome portable from [portableapps.com](https://portableapps.com/de/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) which doesn't use `AppData`, or are you using the normal release as portable?

Comment: @harrymc The portable Chrome programs are clearly are making reference to AppData somewhere if moving to a new install of Windows on the same machine (with the old AppData directory removed).

Comment: You are saying in effect that portable Chrome is not portable. You could verify it using [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and filter on the Chrome executable and on accesses to `AppData`, and if this happens then launch an inquiry on the `portableapps.com` forum asking for it to be rectified.